# class definition dependence on runtime

Tags: python, inheritance, superclass

in my webapp I made two different sessionhandler classes inheriting from a class called SessionHandler

Now I'd like to initiate the appropriate handler (dependent on a cookie value.)

Background: My SessionHandler should be the base class of the Controller as it needs to call a Controller backend method otherwise i would assign the handler object to a ctrl member

Is there a way to set the superclass at runtime?

Or other way to solve that? Hope you got what i meant!

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Can you maybe provide a better description if your current architecture, and what you want to achieve (preferably with some code to illustrate)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I entirely understood your question, but are you sure you need to use inheritance? Couldn't the class you need just be a member instead?

Changing the superclass at runtime does not sound like a very good design, if at all possible.

Just to be sure I got you, what you want to do is have Controller inherit from one of the SessionHandlers, but select which one at runtime? I would rather make Controller have a member variable of type SessionHandler.

Comment: yes you're definitely right. I have to rethink it completely.